# How to fetch KML placement marker value in Google Maps API?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, kml

Dear all i am a newbie to Google Maps API. I have a parsed a KML layer in Google Maps API using GeoXML3. Now how do i fetch placement marker value(Name of the place) of KML in Google Maps API **onclick**. Like when a kml layer gets loaded on google maps and i am clicking on any marker ***i should be able to fetch the placement value of the marker in an alert box***. Please find the code that helps me parse a kml on google maps api. Please guide.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>KML Layer</title>
<link href="/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/default.css" rel="stylesheet"      type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"   src="http://geoxml3.googlecode.com/svn/branches/polys/geoxml3.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
  html { height: 100% }
  body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
  #map_canvas { height: 100% }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
function initialize() 
{
var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(75.602836700999987,32.261890444473394);
var myOptions = {
zoom: 2,
center: chicago,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP }

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
//var transitLayer = new google.maps.TransitLayer();   
//transitLayer.setMap(map);
   var geoXml = new geoXML3.parser({map: map, singleInfoWindow: true});
   geoXml.parse('kmload.kml'); 
   var geoXml1 = new geoXML3.parser({map: map, singleInfoWindow: true});
   geoXml1.parse('lines.kml'); 

   }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
 <div id="map_canvas"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for? I have added the alert in the onclick function which displays me the name of the placemark in the alert box. Please check and let me know if you find any issues.

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://geoxml3.googlecode.com/svn/branches/polys/geoxml3.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://geoxml3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ProjectedOverlay.js"></script>


<title>KML Placement Value Test</title>
<style> 
html, body, #map_canvas {
    height: 100%;
    margin:  0;
    padding: 0;
}

#panel {
    top: 5px;
    left: 85%;
    margin-left: -180px;
    z-index: 5;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
}
.infowindow * {font-size: 90%; margin: 0}
</style>

 <script type="text/javascript" >
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var geoXml = null;
    var geoXmlDoc = null;
    var map = null;
    var myLatLng = null;
    var myGeoXml3Zoom = true;
    var marker = [];
    var polyline;


    function initialize() 
    {
          myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(37.422104808,-122.0838851);
          var test;
          var lat = 37.422104808;
          var lng = -122.0838851;
          var zoom = 18;
          var maptype = google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP;
          if (!isNaN(lat) && !isNaN(lng)) 
          {
                myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
           }
                var myOptions = {zoom: zoom,center: myLatLng,mapTypeId: maptype};
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);        
                infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({}); 
                geoXml = new geoXML3.parser({map: map,infoWindow: infowindow,singleInfoWindow: true,zoom: myGeoXml3Zoom, markerOptions: {optimized: false},createMarker: createMarker});
                geoXml.parse('test.kml');             
    };




    var createMarker = function (placemark, doc) {

        var markerOptions = geoXML3.combineOptions(geoXml.options.markerOptions, {
          map:      geoXml.options.map,
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(placemark.Point.coordinates[0].lat, placemark.Point.coordinates[0].lng),
          title:    placemark.name,
         zIndex:   Math.round(placemark.Point.coordinates[0].lat * -100000)<<5,
         icon:     placemark.style.icon,
         shadow:   placemark.style.shadow 
        });

        // Create the marker on the map
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker(markerOptions);
        if (!!doc) {
        doc.markers.push(marker);
        }

        // Set up and create the infowindow if it is not suppressed
        if (!geoXml.options.suppressInfoWindows) {
          var infoWindowOptions = geoXML3.combineOptions(geoXml.options.infoWindowOptions, {
            content: '<div class="geoxml3_infowindow"><h3>' + placemark.name + 
                     '</h3><div>' + placemark.description + '</div></div>',
            pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(0, 2)
          });
          if (geoXml.options.infoWindow) {
            marker.infoWindow = geoXml.options.infoWindow;
          } else {
            marker.infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(infoWindowOptions);
          }
          marker.infoWindowOptions = infoWindowOptions;

          // Infowindow-opening event handler
          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() 
        {            
              alert(placemark.name);           
            this.infoWindow.close();
            marker.infoWindow.setOptions(this.infoWindowOptions);
            this.infoWindow.open(this.map, this);

          });
        }
        placemark.marker = marker;
        return marker;
      };


    </script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
<div id="map_canvas" style="float: left; width: 70%; height: 100%;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use the "afterParse" function to add click listeners to the markers, you can access the data (if you use function closure), example accessing the name:

```
// assign "useTheData" as the after parse function
var geoXml = new geoXML3.parser({map: map, singleInfoWindow: true, afterParse: useTheData});
geoXml.parse('kmload.kml'); 

// function to retain closure on the placemark and associated text
function bindPlacemark(placemark, text) {
  google.maps.event.addListener(placemark,"click", function() {alert(text)});
}

// "afterParse" function, adds click listener to each placemark to "alert" the name
function useTheData(doc) {
  for (var i = 0; i < doc[0].placemarks.length; i++) {
    var placemark = doc[0].placemarks[i].polygon || doc[0].placemarks[i].marker || doc[0].placemarks[i].polyline;
    bindPlacemark(placemark, doc[0].placemarks[i].name);
  }
};
```

[working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_simpleExampleAlertName.html)

Answer (score -2):

hope it can help ;)

```
 /**
  * map
  */
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(39.980278, 4.049835);
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 10,
    center: myLatlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    scrollwheel: false
  }
 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapa'), myOptions);

 var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
 var markerBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
 var markerArray = [];

 function makeMarker(options){
   var pushPin = new google.maps.Marker({map:map});
   pushPin.setOptions(options);
   google.maps.event.addListener(pushPin, 'click', function(){
     infoWindow.setOptions(options);
     infoWindow.open(map, pushPin);
   });
   markerArray.push(pushPin);
   return pushPin;
 }

 google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(){
   infoWindow.close();
 });

 function openMarker(i){
   google.maps.event.trigger(markerArray[i],'click');
 };

 /**
 *markers
 */
 makeMarker({
   position: new google.maps.LatLng(39.943962, 3.891220),
   title: 'Title',
   content: '<div><h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<div>'
 });

openMarker(0);
```

Comment: :Thanks for guiding. But how do i fetch the value "Lorem Ipsum", the value which appears in the info window in an alert box when i click on the marker.????